# AWS CloudFormation with node.js 10.x Update Error "ZipFile can only be used when Runtime is set to <older node.js versions>"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-sdk-nodejs

We are using CloudFormation template to deploy some intermediate code on Lambda function.

We are using ZipFile function to add inline code through CloudFormation.

Current runtime for lambda function is node.js 8.10.
We need to update node version to 10.x.

While updating Lambda using cloudformation we are getting below error:

> ZipFile can only be used when Runtime is set to either of nodejs,
>   nodejs4.3, nodejs6.10, nodejs8.10, python2.7, python3.6, python3.7.

Comment: CloudFormation now supports ZipFile for Node 10.x runtimes as per https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/80.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a known issue. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=303166&tstart=0
As of this writing, it is still an issue. My suggestion is to have super basic code in an S3 bucket and reference that instead of using a zip file and deploy your actually code after the lambda function is created. Alternatively, you can just upload your zip artifact to an S3 bucket. If your code is proprietary be careful about S3.